# Need help removing ";" separator from items within an array, VBscript

Tags: vbscript

My code is pulling from a data cells that lists multiple file paths and use  semicolons " ; " as the separator.  After spliting the data and placing it into an array, I need to remove the semicolons. otherwise my file paths are invalid when they enter the loop.

To clarify: My code works when there is only one file path in the data cell and dies once it hits a cell with multiple paths because of the ";"

ANY HELP would be much appreciated.

My code is the following:

```
<%
strValue = RS("ATTACHMENTS")
strAryWords = Split(strValue, ";")

' - strAryWords is now an array
For i = 0 to Ubound(strAryWords)
    Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fileObject = fso.getFile(strAryWords(i))

    Response.Write "<TH><TR align=left><TD>" & strAryWords(i) &"  "& fileObject.Size &"  "&"<img src=images/up.gif><BR></TD></TR>"

    Set fileObject = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing  
Next
%>
```

Comment: Please state which language you are using (visual basic?), and tag the question accordingly.

Comment: added 'vb.net beginner' tags.

Comment: Looks like Classic ASP unless my eyes deceive me :)

Comment: Sebastian why did you retag VB.NET when the person that asked the question retaged VBScript?

Comment: It is not vb.net. It is or Vb 6 or Vbscript

Comment: I know its not Blame Sebastian..... I changed the TAG BACK to VBScript(what judy had) but don't have high enough REP to change the title back

Comment: The code in your question works for me as-is; what error are you getting (if any) when it fails? The Split function doesn't include the  split character in its output, so I don't think that's your problem.

Comment: I can force an error if strValue has a trailing semi-colon (Invalid procedure call or argument); can this be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is strValue has a trailing ';', change your code to this:

```
strValue = RS("ATTACHMENTS")
strAryWords = Split(strValue, ";")


' - strAryWords is now an array
For i = 0 to Ubound(strAryWords)
    If strAryWords(i) <> "" Then
        Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fileObject = fso.getFile(strAryWords(i))

        Response.Write "<TH><TR align=left><TD>" & strAryWords(i) &"  "& fileObject.Size &"  "&"<img src=images/up.gif><BR></TD></TR>"

        Set fileObject = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing
    End If
NEXT
```